# Delete an array element based on a value that contains a date in PHP 7

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to delete array elements older than 1 month.
All array elements contains a date value which I'm trying to compare in PHP using `strtotime` +1 month.

The array looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "userid": "f2eca630-f89a-4b7f-b463-d834a2b50a24",
    "name": "4q9fenYDD3Czy2fyTkQmIlvj-1590978189-9BBNrQE5.webp",
    "gender": "female",
    "rating": 61231,
    "date": "2020-04-08 02:23:09",
    "description": ""
  },
  {
    "userid": "f2eca630-f89a-4b7f-b463-d834a2b50a24",
    "name": "o0SuDVEytVBIMJkveNWamamF-1590990218-27UmvlNd.webp",
    "gender": "male",
    "rating": 0,
    "date": "2020-06-01 03:41:38",
    "description": ""
  }
]
```

I'm checking the array with the following PHP code:

```
$datenow = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$expireDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime('+1 month',strtotime($datenow)));

foreach ($monthlyArray as $key => $item) {
    $gotDate = $item['date'];
    echo "Comparing Array Date: ($gotDate) with Current Date +1 month: ($expireDate) <br>";
    if ($gotDate > $expireDate) {
        echo $gotDate . " will be removed because of: " . $expireDate ."<br>";
        //unset ($monthlyArray[$key]);
    }
}
```

*Note that* **$monthlyArray** *contains the array above.*

The results I get when I run this code:

```
Comparing Array Date: (2020-04-08 02:23:09) with Current Date +1 month: (2020-06-01 09:19:09)
Comparing Array Date: (2020-06-01 03:41:38) with Current Date +1 month: (2020-06-01 09:19:09)
```

As you can see, the `if ($gotDate > $expireDate)` didn't get fired which is very odd because the first element in the array has a date set to 2020-04-08 02:23:09 which is indeed more than 1 month old.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: compare both dates by turning unix timestamps or datetime objects, not as strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have your logic the wrong way round; you should be comparing the datetime in `$item` plus one month with the current datetime, and if it's earlier than that, the item has expired and should be deleted. You can use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove the expired items from the array:

```
$monthlyArray = array_filter($monthlyArray, function ($item) {
    $expiry = (new DateTime($item['date']))->modify('+1 month');
    $now = new DateTime();
    return $expiry >= $now;
});

print_r($monthlyArray);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [userid] => f2eca630-f89a-4b7f-b463-d834a2b50a24
            [name] => o0SuDVEytVBIMJkveNWamamF-1590990218-27UmvlNd.webp
            [gender] => male
            [rating] => 0
            [date] => 2020-06-01 03:41:38
            [description] => 
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/27ZMs)

If performance is an issue, pre-computing `$now` and using `strtotime` will be more efficient:

```
$now = time();
$monthlyArray = array_filter($monthlyArray, function ($item) use ($now) {
    $expiry = strtotime('+1 month', strtotime($item['date']));
    return $expiry >= $now;
});
```

and a simple `foreach` with `unset` is probably faster still:

```
$now = time();
foreach ($monthlyArray as $key => $item) {
    $expiry = strtotime('+1 month', strtotime($item['date']));
    if ($expiry < $now) unset($monthlyArray[$key]);
}
```

Comment: `I think you have your logic the wrong way round;`
well this was embarrassing..
You are absolutely right.
Thank you!

Comment: I must also thank you for the bonus of using array_filter. I think array_filter might be less resource heavy.

Comment: @Persson given that you have to loop the entire array, `array_filter` makes (to me) writing the logic a lot simpler. It does have the overhead of a function call though so may not be more performant than a simple for loop with unset. If you're doing this a lot it is probably worth benchmarking.

Comment: I have to do this every 30 minutes and the array contains about 23k elements and increasing by the hour.
Should I look into benchmarking ?

Comment: @Persson I would say it probably is worthwhile. If this data is coming from a database it might also be better to do this filtering directly in the query. You might also want to consider adding an `expired` flag to entries in that situation.

Comment: This data is indeed coming from a database but it has only been fetched once and is then assigned to three arrays. One array who is rearranged based on rating (highest rating to lowest) and the monthly one also requires the same structure which is why I thought it would be smarter to reuse 1 of those arrays and then just filter out the oldies. I might be very wrong here. Should I go for a second connection to the database instead?

Comment: @Persson no, one connection would be better. You might want to consider adding a `date < now() - interval 1 month AS expired` column to your query (I'm assuming MySQL) though; then you'll get a simple boolean to filter the array on.

Comment: Alternatively you might want to consider running a regular job to set an expired flag in the database so you don't have to do this computation on every fetch.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant "should I make a second **query**" not "create a new connection", the connection is still open at this point in the code.
I am considering that, feels like MySQL might be faster in filtering this than me doing it with PHP, how ever, that would require a second while loop to loop through the results but the monthly data is not near as heavy as the total i'm fetching in the first query.

Comment: @Persson it's ok, I meant query too! :-P it's possible it could be faster; once again I think it's one of those things which you'll need to test on your actual system to see which is more optimal. btw this is probably the most performant way to write the above code: https://rextester.com/ZIL33131

Comment: Ah, then I think I'm gonna stick with my plan as I've already fetched alot of data.
I'm gonna do some benchmarking, I can see that the code you posted is faster by 0.051 seconds. Maybe add that link (or the code) in your answer in case anyone else checks this question out haha.

Comment: @Persson good idea; I've added that and also a straight `foreach` loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing timestamps instead of `date` objects :

```
$datenow = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$expireDateTimestamp = strtotime('+1 month',strtotime($datenow));
$expireDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $expireDateTimestamp);

foreach ($monthlyArray as $key => $item) {
    $gotDate = $item['date'];
    $gotDateTimestamp = strotime($gotDate);
    echo "Comparing Array Date: ($gotDate) with Current Date +1 month: ($expireDate) <br>";
    if ($gotDateTimestamp > $expireDateTimestamp) {
        echo $gotDate . " will be removed because of: " . $expireDate ."<br>";
        //unset ($monthlyArray[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you are right regarding the timestamps but as it turns out I had my logic the wrong way round. Coding marathon tend to do this to me haha.

Answer (score 0):

Simply compare the Dates

```
// $datenow = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$expireDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime('-1 month'));

foreach ($monthlyArray as $key => $item) {
    $gotDate = $item['date'];
    echo "Comparing Array Date: ($gotDate) with Current Date +1 month: ($expireDate) <br>";
    if ($gotDate < $expireDate) {
        echo $gotDate . " will be removed because of: " . $expireDate ."<br>";
        //unset ($monthlyArray[$key]);
    }
}
```